# Status bar casting shadow onto Fragment Toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I moved a toolbar from my activity layout into a fragment layout and now the status bar is casting a fuzzy shadow onto the toolbar (top image) instead of having a sharp delineation where the status bar stops and the toolbar begins (bottom image). Anyone know how to fix this (i.e. prevent the status bar from casting a shadow onto the fragment toolbar)?

[image]

Activity:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_frag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Activity adds the fragment to my_frag

Fragment calls setSupportActionBar with my_toolbar

Comment: Please post code which can be used to reproduce your issue

Comment: @fractalwrench updated

Comment: Does the same behaviour happen without the toolbar in the fragment layout?

Comment: @fractalwrench The bottom image is what happens if the toolbar is in the activity layout, the top image is what happens when the toolbar is moved into the fragment layout instead of the activity layout.  I'm migrating it to the fragment because I'm going to do stuff with coordinator layout and gridview.